# Will the new Flutter-based install wizard support Orca? (screen-reading application)

Tags: ubiquity, accessibility, orca

Following the announcement of the new Ubuntu installer application based on Google's Flutter, a few of our sight-challenged members (in our Ubuntu CZ/SK community) has raised an important question. Will the new install wizard support (or be supported by) Orca? Right now, Ubuntu is among the most disability-friendly Linux distribution, lagging just slightly behind the likes of macOS. Our vision-impaired friends are proud to be able to install and maintain their Linux boxes without the need of sighted-person's assistance and they would really like it to stay so.

Unfortunatelly, according to them, Orca doesn't really work with anything but GTK+ applications. Is there any contiguency plan for sightless or otherwise disabled users? Possibly an alternative image with Ubiquiti or added support for screen reading with Flutter?

Comment: Discussion of the new installer, currently under development, should take place in the proper thread: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/refreshing-the-ubuntu-desktop-installer/20659/. Pro Tip: Read the entire thread before asking questions that have already been asked and answered. You don't want to look like a chump. Since this is not released software, it's off-topic here

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check out that thread.